# Socks 5 на PHP

Tags: perl, php, java, сеть, сокет

Привет.

У меня такой вопрос.
Мне нужен socks5 на php, в который я буду отправлять инфу.
Этот socks зашифрует трафик и перенаправит в другой socks с подменой получателя на некий мой сервер, где мой скрипт расшифрует трафик и отправит конечному адресату.

Ответ, полученный на этом сервере, должен быть опять зашифрован и отослан мне обратно.

Как бы это реализовать?

Возможна реализация java, perl, etc.